# build error while building phonegap app using ionic

Tags: java, android, angularjs, cordova, ant

I need to build an phonegap app using angularjs . so i choose ionic framework. these are the steps, I have done so far.

1.set up java,ant, adt and their path.
2.installed ionic using command

```
npm install -g ionic
```

3.started ionic project using

```
ionic ionic start ex1
```

4.added ionic platform

```
ionic platform add android
```

5.builded using command

```
ionic build android
```

But doing building, it shows error.

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Android\adt-bundle\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:932: The following error occurred
while executing this line:
C:\Android\adt-bundle\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:950: null returned: -1073741819

Total time: 11 seconds

C:\Android\fresh\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,C:\Android\fresh\pla
tforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
```

I hadn't modified any code still. and apache ant and java are also working. Why this error?

the contents in C:\Android\adt-bundle\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml is added below

```
line 930  <target name="-package-resources" depends="-crunch">
                <!-- only package resources if *not* a library project -->
line 932    <do-only-if-not-library elseText="Library project: do not package resources..." >
              <aapt executable="${aapt}"
                    command="package"
                    versioncode="${version.code}"
                    versionname="${version.name}"
                    debug="${build.is.packaging.debug}"
                    manifest="${out.manifest.abs.file}"
                    assets="${asset.absolute.dir}"
                    androidjar="${project.target.android.jar}"
                    apkfolder="${out.absolute.dir}"
                    nocrunch="${build.packaging.nocrunch}"
                    resourcefilename="${resource.package.file.name}"
                    resourcefilter="${aapt.resource.filter}"
                    libraryResFolderPathRefid="project.library.res.folder.path"
                    libraryPackagesRefid="project.library.packages"
                    libraryRFileRefid="project.library.bin.r.file.path"
                    previousBuildType="${build.last.target}"
                    buildType="${build.target}"
line 950            ignoreAssets="${aapt.ignore.assets}">
                <res path="${out.res.absolute.dir}" />
                <res path="${resource.absolute.dir}" />
                <!-- <nocompress /> forces no compression on any files in assets or res/raw -->
                <!-- <nocompress extension="xml" /> forces no compression on specific file extensions in assets and res/raw -->
            </aapt>
        </do-only-if-not-library>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error -1073741819  is due to bug in aapt.exe file build-tools in sdk for windows users.

Replace the aapt.exe file with this file https://android.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=776290120000&name=aapt.exe.zip&token=ABZ6GAcRj6lR-sOmUyVguB0Gmf_BI4Z7Gg%3A1415016896298

for more information, Check this page

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77629